# Highlight words in a PDF using PDFBox 1.8.9 and VB Net

Tags: vb.net, pdfbox, highlight

I am trying to Highlight words in a PDF using PDFBox 1.8.9 and VB Net.

I have a list of words which I need to highlight in a pdf.  I don't know their locations, I just have a list.

I am trying to use PDFBox as the library to help me but every reference I have found points to Java which I have no experience with.

I am using PDFBox to parse the text and annotations, but am really struggling with the highlighting.

I know this probably seems like old ground that has been covered before.  But as I said, every reference I had found points to Java.  I have been trying for over 3 weeks to get this to work, with no success!

I have tried iTextSharp, Acrobat.tlb with mixed success but really want to get this to work with PDFBox.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe share some of the code you have up to now for PDFBox

Comment: The only code I have is for parsing text and annotations, I literally have nothing for highlighting and cannot find anything either.

Comment: There is a tool that comes near to this (DrawPrintTextLocations.java) but it is for 2.0.*. PDFBox 1.8 is not very good with fonts. And you should not use IKVM (you mention VB Net), this is not maintained anymore. 1.8 has a PrintTextLocations.java example, but this just gives the locations and doesn't paint anything (which is quite tricky, because of the many different font types).

Comment: Thanks Tilman, do you know if there is a .net version of PDFBox 2.0 available?

Comment: I don't know. Even the 1.8 .net version was not supported by the team. If you insist on using PDFBox, you should learn java.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You are right of course, I have started looking at Java and Eclipse, but it's a huge learning curve even understanding the prerequisites before writing any code!